# CPanel on non-hosting server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm subscribing a dedicated server on iWeb webhosting, i'm going to use this server as a test node but still accessible on web, do i need cpanel to configure? since i'm not that good with linux (ubuntu) console. btw, it'll only host my own web server daemon (not apache/nginx) for a single domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you certainly don't need cPanel. In fact, even though there's a bit of learning curve to doing everything through the command line, learning to do so is a very valuable skill that you will use through the rest of your career. By letting go of cPanel and doing everything through the CLI, you gain a much better understanding of what is happening "under the covers". This will not only make you a better developer, but will also help you to troubleshoot any issues that come up in the future.

Comment: Thanks, for starter i'll look into webmin to configure everything.

Comment: I don't think webmin was quite what Erik was getting at, but its a step in the right direction

Comment: @Mark - yep. More typing, less clicking.